# Mover sidebar para a direita

Tags: php, css

Estou tentando mover minha sidebar com o bootstrap em css para a **direta**. mas não estou conseguindo.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

**SIDEBAR:**

```
  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

<div class="bg-light border-left" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">ATIVIDADE</div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">teste</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS da SIDEBAR:**

```
    #sidebar-wrapper {
  
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Aqui está funcionando normal, abaixo de 768px a sidebar some e acima disso volta. Seu problema não está claro!

Comment: Isso, aqui também, mas ela está na esquerda da página, tentei deixar na direita mas não consegui @hugocsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara parece que vc copiou esse código, pq tem um monte de css ai desnecessário, e basicamente é colocar um `margin-left: auto` e trocar onde é `left` por `right`

Clique para **exibir em página toda** e vc vai ver a `sidebar` aparecendo pela direita

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: -15em;
    min-height: 100vh;
    -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
    transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  }

  #sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
    padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  #sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
    width: 15rem;
  }

  #wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-wrapper {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <div class="bg-light border-left" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">ATIVIDADE</div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">teste</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Opa mano @hugocsl, obrigado! Claro eu tive que alterar muitas vezes e acabei colocando coisas desnecessárias mesmo, desculpa! Só tem uma coisa, tipo eu tenho um page content que está dando conflito com o side bar. Vou te mandar uma print para você ver. https://prnt.sc/t2wxun. A side bar está ocupando o espaço dela alí, no caso o content teria que ficar do lado. Como poderia solucionar.. Desculpe o incomodo

Comment: @Ezequiel o bagulho ficou feio ai hein... tenta colocar position: absolute nesse componente, as vezes resolve

Comment: Ficou demais haha, quando eu coloco o absolute o sidebar some... `#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;....`

Comment: @Ezequiel o absolute não é no sidebar, é no outro container, no container que está ficando para baixo

Comment: `.container-fluid {
  position: absolute;
}` Dessa forma?, não resolveu também... Por isso que eu me compliquei para mover, sempre quando colocava o absolute a sidebar sumia

Comment: Acabava que nunca progredia no código, acabei me perdendo

Comment: Aparentemente o absolute não adiantou, mesmo assim continua daquele formato como consta na print acima https://prnt.sc/t2wxun

Comment: mano se liga nisso, https://prnt.sc/t2xcbz 1236px de margem Kkkk

Comment: @Ezequiel cara se vc não dominar flex, position e display vc não vai conseguir criar nenhum tipo de layout... para uma meia hora para fazer um cursinho de flex no youtube, é de graça e vc vai pegar rapidinho a base. O que eu fiz foi responder a sua pergunta, vc queria a barra na direita, eu coloquei na direita, mas se vc não sabe o que está fazendo vc não vai conseguir terminar o layout só no chute... Com o que vc postou na pergunta o resultado é esse, se vc tiver alguma outra dúvida é só abrir outra pergunta e colocar o código que apresente o problema, assim eu ou outro pode te ajudar

Comment: ta bem, obrigado!

Comment: ...........